# JFace : How to disable textviewer selectAll?

Tags: swt, jface

I disable keyboard events through st.verifykey to prevent character selection through keyboard Shift + left or shift + right

However, it does not work for Ctrl + a

Could it be a problem with doOperation? Through debugging, it is found that doOperationis not executed

How can I correctly prohibit the selection of characters without disabling the control?

This is a sample code. I want to disable SelectAll .
Also, textviewer cannot be disabled

```
/***
 * point="org.eclipse.ui.commands"
 */
public class OpenGodHandCommand extends AbstractHandler {
    
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog( (Shell)null ) {
            @Override
            protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
                TextViewer textViewer = new TextViewer(parent, SWT.NONE) ;
                return textViewer.getControl() ;
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
                newShell.setSize( 400,300 ) ;
                newShell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
            }
        };
        
        dialog.open() ;
        return null ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for an Eclipse plug-in? In Eclipse select all is done by a key binding to a command handler so the viewer never sees the key event.

Comment: How do I remove this StyledText (or TextViewer) key binding?

Comment: Not a global binding, just this StyledText(or TextViewer)

Comment: It looks like even in a dialog it is the `org.eclipse.ui.edit.selectAll` command handler that is doing the select all. I don't know if there is a way to change the handler used when a dialog is active.

Comment: I added a MaskComposite (SWT.TRANSPARENT | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND) on styledtext

This can meet the demand, but we still look forward to a better solution , Thnk you greg-449